# Doctrine record unknown exception in a Symfony 1.4 backend admin module

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am facing a problem with the admin generator and I am unable to get my way around this after 3 hours of brainstorming and exploring.

The error reads as:

500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException
Unknown record property / related component "option1" on "Questions"

Looking up the WWW, I got a gist of possible alternatives. None of which seem like the answer. option1, does exist under Questions schema. However, it is option_1 so I am not sure why it says option1. More importantly, opening up BaseQuestions.class.php file, it clearly states:

getOption1() retrieves the value of option_1.

Anybody with any answer on this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had just the same problem with a field named `address_2`. Changing the name of the field in the database to `address2` solved the problem. I think that that this is because of the number that confuse the admin generator to translate the name from underscore-separated propriety name to camelCase function name. This issue append only with the admin generator so, if you need to use it you have to change the field name in your DB with `option1`.

Comment: I did exactly this, it's weird but whatever....worked, checked your answer later though! thanks!