# Symfony 1.4 does not create getters for fields with underscore in front of numbers

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, getter, getter-setter

I got a database-table containing fields named like xx_yy_1, xx_yy_2, etc. Unfortunately Doctrine did not generate getters/setters for this fields. I guess this only happens, if there's a underscore in front of a number.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you paste your `schema.yml` with the table that contains these fields?

Comment: You are right, it seems that underscore in front of a number gives some problems. See this [Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371212/doctrine-record-unknown-exception-in-a-symfony-1-4-backend-admin-module/9664220). The only solution I found is to change the name of the fields form `xx_yy_1` to `xx_yy1`...

Comment: I don't like to change the DB-model, as it needs to be synced with an other DB. Are you sure that there's no other solution (like adding getters)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an inconsistent behaviour in Doctrine. You can access does fields like `$record->getXxYy_1()` or `$record->get('xx_yy_1')`. The DocBlock on the top of the generated base model class is wrong, so autocompletion may offer wrong method names for these fields.

Comment: Both of this didn't work.
I added getter-methods to my class extending the base class, but I'm not sure, how to fill them properly. :-/

Comment: You might overlooked something because it's works for me without any modification of model the classes (field names like `address_line_1` can be accessed with `getAddressLine_1()` or `get('address_line_1')`). If you wan a custom getter you can use `return parent::_get('xx_yy_1')` in it as well.

Comment: adding
    public function getXxYy4(){
        return parent::_get('xx_yy_4');
    }
works for me. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a Doctrine problem. You should name your columns without underscore+number, like:

**xx_yy1** instead of **xx_yy_1.**

So, the method is always ->getXxyy1(); or ->get('xx_yy1')

Comment: as written above this would be only an option if absolutely necessary. It would spoil DB-Sync...